# Symfony form: how to render an empty many-to-many relationship but still make it required

Tags: php, symfony

On an old Symfony 5.2 application I inherited, I have two entities: `Users` and `Influencers`. These have a many-to-many relationship between them.

I'm creating a form to create and edit `Influencers` but the form field (a `<select>` HTML element) for the relationship with `Users` is rendered with an option (a user) already selected.

This is not what I want, since it means someone creating a new `Influencer` and not noticing the pre-selected option, will save the form with the wrong User assigned to the `Influencer`. I want the form to start without a `User` selected.

Additionally, I would like a value for the relationship to be required on the form. This means that:

- at least one `User` should be assigned to a newly created `Influencer`;
- when editing and existing `Influencer`, I should not be able to remove all `Users` from the relationship field.

I already tried several combinations of the `allow_add`, `allow_delete`, `required`, and messing with the `choices` options when adding the field with the form builder, but all to no avail.

I just can't figure out how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Here are the relevant parts of the code, simplified for brevity sake.

The Influencer entity in `src/Entity/Influencer.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ........

/* ORM Stuff here... */
class Influencer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="influencers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="influencers_account_managers")
     */
    private $accountManagers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accountManagers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getAccountManagers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->accountManagers;
    }

    public function addAccountManager(User $accountManager): self
    {
        if (!$this->accountManagers->contains($accountManager)) {
            $this->accountManagers[] = $accountManager;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAccountManager(User $accountManager): self
    {
        if ($this->accountManagers->contains($accountManager)) {
            $this->accountManagers->removeElement($accountManager);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

The User entity in `src/Entity/User.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ........

/* ORM Stuff here... */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    // Other properties
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Influencer", mappedBy="accountManagers")
     */
    private $influencers;
```

The InfluencerController in `src/Controller/InfluencerController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use ....

class InfluencerController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/add-influencer", name="influencer_create")
     */
    public function create(Request $request, InfluencerManager $influencerManager)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(InfluencerType::class, new Influencer());

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $influencerManager->create($form->getData());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('influencers_list');
        }

        return $this->render('influencer/create.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

The InfluencerType in `src/Form/InfluencerType.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use .......

class InfluencerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('accountManagers', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
            'required' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype' => true,
            'entry_options' => [
                'class' => User::class,
                'label' => false,
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChoiceType::class instead of CollectionType::class,  and in your User Entity, Influencer must have a relation.

```
 $builder->add('accountManagers', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => '...',
                'choices' => User::Influencer,
                'multiple'  => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                )
            );
```

Comment: Using those options results in a big list of radio boxes, one per user. From reading the docs, it seems I would actually need `expanded` to be `false` and `multiple` to be `true`, because I want a select element and I want it to be possible to associate more than one User. But when I do that, I get an error saying `Unable to transform value for property path "accountManagers": Expected an array.`

Comment: in your Entitys, add :    

 `public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
`

Comment: I already have a `__toString` method on both entities. But how would that help with the expected array?